# Accessing an element in a form that has no id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment as a part of a cyber security course where I am supposed to submit a form with specific values for the inputs.

here is the relevant snippet of the source code I am working with is: (source code for a messaging system)

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputSubject">Subject:</label>
    <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Enter a subject" pattern=".{5,}" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="contents" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message" pattern=".{5,}" required></textarea>
</div>
```

whenever I am trying to set the value of the textarea using either getElementsbyName or getElemetnsbyTagName, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How are you using getElementsByName?  Are you aware that it returns a nodelist (kind of like an array of elements), and not a single element?

Comment: document.getElementsByName('contents')[0].value <<- is this correct assuming that it is the only element with that name?

Comment: Yep that would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Ensure you are correctly referencing the element
2. Set with either `value` or `textContent`.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="contents"]');
textArea.textContent = `whatever you want it to say`.
```

Comment: still getting the same error sadly "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')" -- .textContent

Answer (score 1):

As a getElementsByName return a list of nodes and you only have one element with that name:

This should work for you:

```
document.getElementsByName("contents")[0].value = "hello world"
```

here how you could implemented:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputSubject">Subject:</label>
        <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Enter a subject"
            pattern=".{5,}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="contents" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message" pattern=".{5,}"
            required></textarea>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementsByName('contents')[0].value = 'hello world'
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sadly still getting the same error using this .. Does this search only for the page that is opened or for the whole website .. I am new to javascript to be honest

Comment: @AhdhassanHassan made sure that you have your `script` at the end of the `body` tag

Answer (score 1):

Import a script in your html  with this way `<script defer src="script.js"></script>` so that the DOM tree is created. In your imported script, you can do this: `document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "Test Value";`

Comment: the problem is I am supposed to encode the script into a url and use it for XSS for a user that can only access the website of the messaging system .. would this still work taking this into consideration?

Comment: This command "document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "Test Value";" is correct, so test it with the way you want. Have in mind that dom must loaded first completly.

Answer (score 0):

First: Make sure your textarea does exist in the page, and then call your function, you can use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` function. If your function is executed before textarea is rendered to page, you will get the null exception error.

Second: By all methods like getElement**s** and not getElement (without s) please note -> it is **plural** and not singular.

```
var element = document.getElemetnsByTagName('div');
```

If you want to manipulate them, don't forget to access the Array.

```
element[0].value
```

and not

```
element.value
```

Hope it's helpful.